# Unable to pass formcontrol value to string param

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following FormControls:

```
 username = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
 password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

I then try to pass these values into a method:

```
 await this._as.login(this.username.value, this.password.value).subscribe(result => {

 });
```

Yet I get Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. on this.username.value

The login method is

```
login(username: string, password: string) {}
```

Can someone explain why typescript complains about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: Non-nullable `FormControl`**

According to [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#nullability),

> TypeScript will enforce that you always handle the possibility that the control has become null.

with:

```
username = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

To enforce non-nullable to `FormControl`,

> If you want to make this control non-nullable, you may use the nonNullable option.

```
username = new FormControl('', {
  nonNullable: true,
  validators: [Validators.required],
});
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evvbkb?file=src/main.ts)

---

**Solution 2: Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)**

Alternatively, you can use the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) .

```
await this._as.login(this.username.value ?? '', this.password.value)
  .subscribe(result => {

  });
```